# QTableWidget check right mouse even cell pressed

Tags: c++, qt

I am a beginer with QT.
I want to display menu ( copy, paste, clear) when right-click mouse btuton on QTableWidget. In mainwindow i can use mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event), but in QTableWidget i can't do that.

[image]

Comment: You are probably looking for [`QWidget::setContextMenuPolicy`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#contextMenuPolicy-prop) and [QWidget::customContextMenuRequested](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#customContextMenuRequested).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to have widgets show a context menu from the list of actions you set on the widget. See `QWidget::addAction()` and the related functions. Set the widgets `contextMenuPolicy` to `Qt::ActionsContextMenu` to use this approach. You can also handle the menu manually by modifying the `contextMenuPolicy` to be `Qt::CustomContextMenu` and then connect to the `customContextMenuRequested` signal.